# Correct structure creation

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, graph

This is the beginning portion of an assignment I'm working on. I'm not familiar with structures yet so I just want to know if I've created the beginning portion correctly. The corresponding portions in bold are the statements that I'm not sure if I've followed the guidelines correctly.

The beginning description:

> Start by defining two structure types. All structure types must be
>   documented by saying (1) what a value of this structure represents and
>   (2) what each field represents.
>
> A structure of type **Edge** represents one edge in a graph. It has three
>   fields: two vertex numbers and a weight. Include a parameterless
>   constructor that sets all three fields to 0.
>
> A structure of type **Graph** represents a weighted graph. It has four
>   fields:
>
> the number of vertices in the graph, the number of edges in the graph,
>   **an array of Edges that holds the edges, the physical size of that
>   array of edges. Include a constructor Graph(nv) that yields a graph
>   with nv vertices and no edges. The constructor must create the array
>   of edges.** You can assume that there are no more than 100 edges, but
>   that number must be easy to change. To increase this to 200, for
>   example, should only require changing one line of your program. To
>   achieve that, create a named constant that is the maximum number of
>   edges. For example,
>
> const int maxEdges = 100;
>
> defines constant maxEdges with a value of 100. Any time you need to refer to the maximum number of edges, use maxEdges, not 100.

My development plan for the said description:

```
struct Edge
{
  int vertex1;
  int vertex2;
  int weight;

  Edge()
  {
    vertex1 = 0;
    vertex2 = 0;
    weight = 0;
  }
};

struct Graph
{
  int numOfVert;
  int numOfEdge;
  int arrayOfEdge[];
  const int maxEdges = 100;

  Graph(int nv)
  {
    numOfVert = nv;
    numOfEdge = 0;
    arrayOfEdge[maxEdges];
  }
};
```

I just want to know if I've completely understood what the description is telling me to do. Appreciate any help.

Comment: Apperently you didn't see this: "All structure types must be documented by saying (1) what a value of this structure represents and (2) what each field represents."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have for `Edge` is correct. You can improve your code a little by initializing the members using initializer lists in the constructor.

```
Edge() : vertex1(0), vertex2(0), weight(0)
{
}
```

`Graph` needs a little bit work.

1. Make `maxEdges` a non-member constant.
2. Make `arrayOfEdge` an array of known size.

Here's my suggestion:

```
const int maxEdges = 100;
struct Graph
{
   int numOfVert;
   int numOfEdge;
   int arrayOfEdge[maxEdges];

   Graph(int nv) : numOfVert(nv), numOfEdge(0), arrayOfEdge()
   {
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. A question I have is if I followed your suggestion of making `arrayOfEdge` an array of known size before the constructor, does that mean I am invalidating the guideline that states **The constructor must create the array of edges** ?

Comment: I don't think you would be violating that guideline.